# http.post is being fired twice

Tags: flutter

I am a bit new to Flutter, and I am building a screen that posts data to an API built in PHP mon my hosting server. The API is built by me which receives a JSON object and then saves the data.

The app is working fine, and API is receiving the data, but the http.post seems is firing twice ( calling the API twice)

Which makes my API saves the record twice. there is no possible way for me to check before adding the send record. as My API simply saves a new record so whenever it receives a call it simply saves it and returns back a value for the mobile App ( built in Flutter).

If I use a condition to check, this way the first call will return correct data to the mobile app, but the second one will return an error for the mobile app since the record already exists.

I have read about the Access-Control-Allow-Origin and how it might be the issue and put it my my .httaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

but no luck.

any idea.

Note I am using a shared hosting.

Code I use in Flutter:

```
class _PostADToServerState extends State<PostADToServer> {
Future<List<JSBResponse>> _postRequest() async {
//    print('Call API function is called');
Map<String, dynamic> myAd = {
  "isbn10": widget.title.isbn10,
  "isbn13": widget.title.isbn13,
  ... [Some fields]
  "titleCondition": widget.title.titleCondition,
  "priceIs": widget.title.priceIs,
  "school_name": widget.title.schoolName
};

String json = jsonEncode(myAd);

var url = 'https://www.example.com/xapis/save_new_ad.php';
var body = json;

var data = await http.post(url,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    body: body);

var jsonData = jsonDecode(data.body);
```

Code in my PHP API starts with the following:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$theTitle = json_decode($data);
```

Then I use the content I find in the $theTitle object as the following:

```
$title = $theTitle->title;
```

Comment: Where do you call _postRequest() from?

Comment: are you certain that the HTTP POST is happening twice?  or is it possible that the server side is simply writing out the record twice?  I mean, do you have any other indication of a double-POST other than the double record?  if that's your only indication, you might be looking in the wrong place for the source of the duplicate records

Comment: Yes in AndroidStudio I printed the content of the URL I am posting in the console
    
and its printed twice, also the server request is receiving the POST twice

Comment: Another note: I am reading the values I am posting from a screen, the I navigate to this screen which is posting to server. using Navigator.push with parameters and I pass a class that contains the data I am planning to post to server

Comment: @KevinSaleh Did you finally get this to work cause i m having similar issue. Especially when using await. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on Flutter Web; I changed the http package to dio and that fixed my problem:

https://pub.dev/packages/dio